# PostgreSQL stack depth limit exceeded in hstore query though query is < 2 MB

Tags: r, postgresql, stack-size

I run into `stack depth limit exceeded` when trying to store a row from `R` to `PostgreSQL`. In order to address bulk upserts I have been using a query like this:

```
sql_query_data <- sprintf("BEGIN;
                        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE 
                          ts_updates(ts_key varchar, ts_data hstore, ts_frequency integer) ON COMMIT DROP;
                          INSERT INTO ts_updates(ts_key, ts_data) VALUES %s;
                          LOCK TABLE %s.timeseries_main IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;

                          UPDATE %s.timeseries_main
                          SET ts_data = ts_updates.ts_data,
                          ts_frequency = ts_updates.ts_frequency
                          FROM ts_updates
                          WHERE ts_updates.ts_key = %s.timeseries_main.ts_key;

                          INSERT INTO %s.timeseries_main
                          SELECT ts_updates.ts_key, ts_updates.ts_data, ts_updates.ts_frequency
                          FROM ts_updates
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN %s.timeseries_main ON (%s.timeseries_main.ts_key = ts_updates.ts_key)
                          WHERE %s.timeseries_main.ts_key IS NULL;
                          COMMIT;",
                          values, schema, schema, schema, schema, schema, schema, schema)
```

}

So far this query worked quite well for updating millions of records while holding the number of inserts low. Whenever I ran into stack size problems so far I simply split my records into multiple chunks and go on from there.

However, this strategy faces some trouble now. I don't have a lot of records anymore, but a handful in which the `hstore` is a little bit bigger. But it's not really 'large' by any means. I read suggestions by @Craig Ringer who advises not to near the limit of 1GB. So I assume the size of the hstore itself is not the problem, but I receive this message:

`Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
)`

EDIT: I did increase the limit to 7 MB and ran into the same error stating 7 MB is not enough. This is really odd to me, because I the query itself is only 1.7 MB (checked it by pasting it to a text file). Can anybody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

Increase the max_stack_depth as suggested by the hint. [From the official documentation]
(http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-resource.html):

> The ideal setting for this parameter is the actual stack size limit enforced by the kernel (as set by ulimit -s or local equivalent), less a safety margin of a megabyte or so.

and

> The default setting is two megabytes (2MB), which is conservatively small and unlikely to risk crashes.

Super Users can alter this setting per connection, or it can be set for all users through the postgresql.conf file (requires postgres server restart).

Comment: Thx! hstore is pretty OK here because it helps to keep the numbers of records down and I hardly need subsets. I am only at around 700k an ulimit -s is basically at 10 MB , so I can easily go up a bit from the initial 2 MB .  db and app are on separate servers. Side note: freq is null when irregular.

Comment: glad it worked. by the side note, I wanted to point out, that you could write `ts_frequency = NULL` instead of `ts_frequency = ts_updates.ts_frequency`. Its just shorter code, that's all. Editing answer now. Thanks.

Comment: To increase max_stack_depth permanently you need to edit the config, right? Can't just do it with superuser for all other users and sessions. Is there a way to populate larger hstores. I mean I am nowhere near the max size and the stack seems to be the restriction. Are copy and csv import the only ways to get a moderate 100k pairs in ? Would be the same /w json I suppose...

Comment: yes, edit the config file to permanently set the max_stack_depth. copy is the most efficient way to get data in, the alternative would be via insert queries in smaller batches. the same stack issue *should* apply to json  as it does to hstore (haven't tested, but please let me know if you test it), however, json is a more flexible data format.

Comment: ok this is really strange: I followed your advice and increased the limit to 7MB after checking `ulimit -s` . I did work, but now PG complains that 7MB is not enough, which is odd because I pasted the query into a textfile and it only had 1.7 MB. Is there any explanation for that ?

Comment: i'm not sure what's going on in your case. are you saying the increase worked for a bit, but with new data, it exceeded the stack depth limit? Could you post a sample of the data that are being inserted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108632/discussion-between-haleemur-ali-and-matt-bannert).